# Coldfusion: How to dump out arguments scope with cfthrow?

Tags: coldfusion

After my form submits I am calling a controller method that runs an orm EntitySave in my cfc.  I would like to dump out the arguments before I save my data via ORM just to visually validate those are indeed the values I want to save in the database.
So when I use this

```
<cfthrow message="value = #arguments#">
```

I am getting this:

```
Error: Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.
```

I understand you are not allowed to do this with complex objects, so in those cases I would use `<cfdump>` but I can't find a way to dump in a `<cfthrow>`. I am sure there is a better way to accomplish this. I have also tried doing a `<cfmail>` to myself which works amazingly but the email will take a minute or two. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am currently checking into ValidateThis.

Comment: If this is for a permanent solution (not just temp debugging), investigate something like [BugLog HQ](http://bugloghq.riaforge.org) which lets you log errors via a web service and then browse/analyse aggregated reports via a webapp.

Comment: In the same vein as @PeterBoughton's comment, you could also check out [Hoth](http://aarongreenlee.com/share/hoth-coldfusion-errors-tracking-reporting/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could serialise it:

```
<cfthrow message="value = #serializeJson(arguments)#">
```

But I don't think you want that sort of thing showing up on the screen.

I'd log it if I was you (so same notion, just `<cflog>` before the `<cfthrow>`, and put the arguments in the log entry, and in the `<cfthrow>` just put a brief explanation of the error (you should also use a TYPE attribute, for subsequent handling of the exception that you've raised.

Comment: Thanks Adam your answer worked too. One upvote, I just downloaded a plugin for Sublime Text to prettify the json.

Comment: I've started using this approach for writing complex values to log files recently and it's been really useful. Some functions I have can accept simple values or complex objects and I no longer need to care that much which I get.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than throwing it, you could try dumping it to a file and see if that meets your needs:

```
<cfdump var="#arguments#" output="C:\dump.html" format="html">
```

If you need to abort (as a throw would do), you can add abort on to the end of the tag, `<cfdump... abort>`.

Comment: Thanks @ss992, this gives me a nice visual. Is there anyway I could prepend the log instead of append?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to prepend using `cfdump`, but for a quick solution you could set your output file to be timestamped, i.e. `output="C:\dump-#now()#.html"` or something like that. You'll stack up a lot of dump files, but they'll be a little easier to manage than a single file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in order to use `<cfdump>`:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="arguments_dump">
    <cfdump var="#arguments#" />
</cfsavecontent>
<cfthrow message="#arguments_dump#" />
```

Takes a little bit more code however and is not as elegant as Adam Cameron's answer above.